# What should I use to share functionality, module or class?

Tags: ruby, oop

I have a code that looks and works the same in the both situations, either:

```
class Bar
  def baz
    puts 3
  end
end

class Foo < Bar
end

Foo.new.baz
#=> 3
```

or:

```
module Bar
  def baz
    puts 3
  end
end

class Foo
  include Bar
end

Foo.new.baz
#=> 3
```

What should I prefer to use when designing functionality that is shared by multiple models?

Comment: Ask yourself if `Foo` really *is* a `Baz`. If so, inheritance may be OK. Generally though, you should favor [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) and choose the module approach.

Comment: @w0lf that's make the sense, i just want tot understand this [Prefer classes to modules when designing functionality that is shared by multiple models.](https://github.com/thoughtbot/guides/tree/master/best-practices#ruby)

Comment: *Prefer classes to modules when designing functionality that is shared by multiple models.* doesn't mean inheritance instead of module. It means: If your model has complex logic, it is preferred to put that logic into a class on its own. The man reason is that it is easier to test one class in isolation, then testing the same module included into multiple classes.

Comment: [*"Inheritance is for specialization, not for sharing code"*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9lv2lBq6x4A&feature=youtu.be&t=30m47s) – Sandi Metz

Comment: @Stefan great talk by Sandi, love it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use `Bar` without the existence of `Foo` (or any other class), then you need to define `Bar` as an independent class, which means that you need to inherit `Bar` by `Foo`.

If you are going to use `Bar` only to add functionalities to `Foo` (or any other class) or to modify them, then you should define `Bar` as a module. Also notice that you can inherit `Bar` by `Foo` only when you create `Foo` for the first time, which means that afterthought-adding of functionality would usually have to be done as including a module rather than inheriting a class.

In short, if `Bar` has the primary existence, then let `Bar` be a class, and inherit it by `Foo`. If `Foo` has the primary existence, then define a module `Bar`, and include it into `Foo`.

Answer (score 2):

in her brilliant book [Practical Object-Oriented Design in Ruby](http://www.poodr.com/) Sandi Metz describes these considerations very well.

In short, as [@w0lf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390819/w0lf) mentioned in his comment to the question, unless `Foo` ***is a*** `Bar` you want to use composition.

Answer (score 0):

I used module mixins very often to bring in a special functionality. May be to clean up or filter forbidden words from text attributes of some models which have no inheritance.

If you have real inheritance then use it.